# org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.gerrit.core.client.GerritLoginException

Tags: git, gerrit, collabnet, giteye

I am using CollabNet GitEye for the first time and I'm receiving an error while trying to visualize my gerrit changes of a project.
[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this?